# What good programming practices will change with C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, "Don't return objects by value if they are expensive to copy" (RVO can't always be used). This advice might change because of rvalue references.

The same might be said about storing collections of pointers to objects, because copying them by value into the collection was too expensive; this reason might no longer be valid.

Or the use of enums might be discouraged in favour of "enum class".

What other practices or tips will change?

Comment: Questions with multiple different correct answers should be community wiki

Comment: @Jon - I realize you're new, but one of the aspects of the site is to accept answers to your questions so that future searchers with the same problem know which one solved yours.  If there is one answer that best answers your question, use the check mark next to the answer to select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I have accepted an answer now. I'm concerned that marking answers that didn't completely solve the problem as accepted will discourage further answers. Anyway this is meta.

Comment: @Jon -- completely understand and I'm not encouraging you accept answers merely to improve a metric.  Generally, though, you will get a good enough answer and you ought to accept it if it's the best.  You can always comment on the answer and perhaps get it improved.  I just thought you might not be aware of that aspect of the site since you're relatively new.

Comment: Just a question, is it still called C++ 0x? or c++ xx ? Since were in like 2010 now

Comment: @Faisal:  C++0x is just an informal name, and most people will probably stick with it until the standard is actually published, at which point it will be C++11 or C++12, depending on when that actually happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I expect that C++ written in a functional-like style will become more prevalent because:

- Lambda expressions make using the standard library algorithms much easier
- Move semantics make returning standard library or other RAII container objects significantly cheaper

Comment: Regarding move semantics: or any "resource owner" class. We could even return locks now :)

Comment: @Matthieu:  Right; I meant "container" in the "RAII container" sense, not the "standard library container" sense; I've added language to clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm marking this as the best answer; but I suspect this can be expanded as C++0x becomes more prevalent.

Answer (score 6):

Improved code locality by using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Rvalue references is not a replacement for [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) or [NRVO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(VS.80).aspx). Returning large things by value is still silly - it's just less silly when the class is actually small and holds heap memory. Passing in a reference to the return value is still best practice, imo.

Function objects as raw structs/classes will be deprecated in favour of lambdas.

I can't really think of much, to be honest. C++0x seems to make existing code simpler, rather than actually change it.

Comment: "C++0x seems to make existing code simpler, rather than actually change it." Exactly. The master said: "Source Code Rejuvenation is not Refactoring"